# Remove leaf level row in ag grid

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have a requirement where I need to delete/hide leaf level record in ag grid since it shows the confusing behavior to the end user. As shown in the screenshot I need to delete/hide last records(highlighted in red) in each group since the record above it depicts the same data.

[image]

I have tried to remove using updateRowData like this:

```
 this.gridApi.forEachLeafNode(function(rowNode, index) {
     self.gridApi.updateRowData({ remove: [rowNode.data] });
   });
```

The above piece of code deletes all data since in my case the data shown in 2nd and 3rd(leaf) level are same. Is there anyway I can delete only the one's that are marked in red.

Also I have tried other techniques like adding data to leaf level records as the document suggests, but nothing worked.

PS: Deleting may not be the only option. If its possible not to render then also the requirement will be fulfilled. Any guidance will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the best one, but here is one solutions.

Say you have your grid template something like this

```
<ag-grid-angular
  #agGrid
  [rowData]="rowData"
  ... // snip!
  [getDataPath]="getDataPath"  // This one is key
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
></ag-grid-angular>
```

And data something like this:

```
this.rowData = [
  { entry: ['A'] },
  {
    entry: ['A', 'B'],
  },
  {
    entry: ['C', 'D'],
  },
  {
    entry: ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H'],
  },
];
```

Later when you declare the functions:

```
this.getDataPath = function(data) {
  // This returns the hiarchy normally
  return data.entry;     
};
```

But what if we could modify it a little?

```
this.getDataPath = function(data) {
  // If there are more than two levels, we'll just slice those off.        
  if( data.entry.length > 2 ) {
    return data.entry.slice(0,2);
  }
  return data.entry;
};
```

Of course we could compare values or filter before we slice.

(I've barely touched angular, but I followed the plunker links from here https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tree-data/ and did some simple editing.)

Comment: Ok. Looks like a good idea .. I will give it a try and let you know . Thanks for the reply and suggestion ..

Comment: looks like this solution will work if we have have gridOptions.treeData = true . In my case gridOptions.treeData = false, if I were to make it true it would make the implementation complex and change the entire design.

Comment: My mistake, I assumed from the image that you were using treeData.

Comment: Sorry for not giving that information. Any idea for this kind of scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll find that if you enable Pivoting as explained [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/pivoting/) it'll no longer show the final leaf-nodes. There are however many side-effects of swapping to PivotMode which you should test against.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the answer incase anyone comes up with similar requirement.

We can do it by adding '[externalRowFilter](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/filter-external/)'.

What you need to do is enable the filter by default and then filter out the leaf nodes:

```
isExternalFilterPresent: () => return true,

doesExternalFilterPass: (node) => return node.data.group,
```